# is it possible to change the PS line in powershell to be highlighted?

Tags: powershell

Say I have a powershell line that looks like this:

```
PS C:\Dev\Apps>
```

Is it possible to modify that so that it is highlighted in, say, yellow? I'd like to be able to make all of the command lines "pop" a bit more. In a big wall of text it's really hard to scan and see the important parts (i.e. the commands you ran). I've browsed a few articles about Powershell and don't see any way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
function prompt
{
    Write-Host ("PS " + $(get-location) +">") -nonewline -backgroundcolor yellow -foregroundcolor black
    return " "
}
```

Comment: And see `help about_prompts` and `help about_profiles` for more information.

Comment: Wow. Copy, paste, exec, done!